# @angular-redux implementation

Tags: angular-redux

I am implementing redux in my test application for managing the app state, My current scenario is I need hit the backend service and update the response back to my app state once service success. Henceforth I implemented effects which will handle hitting backend service and update the app state separating from reducer. But effects is not getting called after dispatching the action
Please check the configuration made and suggest me if I am missing something.

package.json

```
"@angular-redux/form": "^9.0.1",
"@angular-redux/router": "^9.0.0",
"@angular-redux/store": "^9.0.0",

"@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "^6.1.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^6.1.0",
```

Inside app.module.ts

```
EffectsModule.forRoot([TestEffects])
```

Inside Component (Dispatch)

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch({ type: 'GET_FEEDS' })
}
```

Inside effects Test.Effects

```
  @Effect()
   loadFeeds$: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
       ofType('GET_FEEDS'),
       switchMap((action) =>
           this.feedService.getFeed().pipe(
              map(feeds => console.log("Data received ..." + feeds)),
              catchError(error => of(console.log("Error ..." + error))),
          )
       )
   )
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain exactly _what_ you're trying to achieve, and what is currently not working.

Comment: @JessedeBruijne please check now.